# Rake aborted! Rails can't generate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I'm learning rails and going step by step with lynda video series. 
I tried rake . It gives following error.

```
$ rake generate migration DoNothingYet 
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'generate'
```

I used --trace to find the problem. However, it doesn't point the error.

```
$ rake generate migration DoNothingYet --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'generate'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/boss/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
```

Comment: the actual command is
 rails generate migration DoNothingYet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `rails` command, not `rake` for this:

```
rails generate migration DoNothingYet
```

Good luck!

Comment: @lenso_here - you are not! Actually, this is something that confuses a lot of people learning rails. It has been decided, to replace `rake` commands with `rails` in [Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18878)

Comment: I see. Why do you think cursor is just blinking and stuck there? nothing happenig

Comment: I just rebooted my mac and it fixed the problem. Thanks again.